# XSLT find word near another word

Tags: xslt, text

How can i find, with XSLT, the word before and after another know word in a text node?

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.x solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

**I. In XSLT 2.x / XPath 2.x one can use the functions [tokenize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) and [index-of()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-index-of) to produce the desired results with one-liner XPath expressions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pWord" select="'three'"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:sequence select=
    "tokenize(., ',\s*')
        [index-of(tokenize(current(), ',\s*'), $pWord) -1]"/>

   <xsl:sequence select=
    "tokenize(., ',\s*')
        [index-of(tokenize(current(), ',\s*'), $pWord) +1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>One, two, three, four</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
two four
```

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**

It is possible to solve the same task in XSLT 1.0 using the  `strSplit-to-Words` template of **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
>
   <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:param name="pWord" select="'three'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vrtfwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" 
                          select="', &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes"
         select="ext:node-set($vrtfwordNodes)/*"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vserchWordPos" select=
      "count($vwordNodes
                 [. = $pWord]/preceding-sibling::*
             ) +1"/>

      <xsl:value-of select=
       "concat($vwordNodes[$vserchWordPos -1],
               ' ',
               $vwordNodes[$vserchWordPos +1]
               )
       "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document**:

```
<t>One, two, three, four</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
two four
```